# DAX: Does a column contain a specific value, with GROUP BY

Tags: group-by, powerbi, dax

Let's say (in Power BI) I have a table of account numbers and activity status (active or inactive):

```
Account  | Status
---------------------
123000   | Inactive
456000   | Inactive
123000   | Active
456000   | Inactive
789000   | Inactive
```

Rows can be duplicates; an account can appear many times with varying status. What I want is a measure or calculated column that shows whether or not a given account number is active on ANY row. So, group by account number, if "active" is found, new column/measure = "active"/TRUE/etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the `Account` column in a table or matrix visual, then all you need for your measure is

```
StatusMeasure = MIN ( AccountsTable[Status] )
```

This takes the first of all the `Status` values alphabetically so if one of the values is `"Active"` that's what it will show (otherwise `"Inactive"`).

Comment: Thank you, I'm marking this as the answer because after knowing that MIN and MAX work alphabetically, my question is essentially "how do you use group by in DAX?" For anyone wondering I solved it using the following calculated column: 
`NewColumn = CALCULATE(MAX('Table'[Status]),ALLEXCEPT('Table','Table'[Account]))`